# Tabular Partitioning - How to add a column without breaking everything?

Tags: ssas, partitioning, tabular

we are facing a problem regarding an Analysis Services tabular model deployment with a fact table having several partitions in order to speed up processing times.

The fact table has several millions row per partition and the partition strategy is date-driven (daily partitioning).

Right now, the requirement is to add a column to this fact table.
It is ok if only the most recent partitions have the new column.

Is it possible via Visual Studio to add a column to the table, deploy the model having the new column without having to process all the partitions of the table again?

If we try, Visual Studio shows a non-explaining "Error" message.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must process all partitions, because if you add column and refresh only few partitions then you get a error "Cannot query internal supporting structures for column "NewColumnName" because they are not processed. Please refresh or recalculate the table.